# How to merge data from all files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of data files and I want to merge the Maximum Amplitudes from each of them into one column titled 'Max Amp'.

So far I am doing this which gives me almost exactly what I want but each file has its own separate column.

```py
for z in csv_files:
    # read the csv file
    af = pd.read_csv(z, skiprows=3)
    tf= (max(af))
    gf=pd.DataFrame([tf], columns=["Max Amp"])
    display(gf)
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the csv files are the same format and columns, try using pd.concat(dataframelist)

Put the dataframes to be joined in a list:

```
dataframelist = [df1, df2, ..]
combined_df = pd.concat(dataframelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to obtain the data as a list and then put it into the desired dataframe

```
data_list = []
for z in csv_files:
    af = pd.read_csv(z, skiprows=3)
    data_list.append(max(af['Max Amp']))

new_df['Max Amp'] = data_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a pandas Series when you say you want one column, you can find the max from each DataFrame and append them to one another with the name of the file as the index.

```
values = []
index = []
for z in csv_files:
    # read the csv file
    values.append(max(z))
    index.append(z)
print(pd.Series(values, index = index, name = 'Max Amp'))
```